# Inserir sub-total por página em uma tabela do Report (.NET) RDLC

Tags: c#, vb.net, relatório

Preciso inserir sub-total cumulativo em cada uma das páginas do meu relatório RDLC .NET, estou utilizando uma tabela para alocar todos os valores dos campos e suas somatorias.

A grande dificuldade, é inserir o total dentro de uma das celulas desta tabela.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa adicionar novos grupos no seu `tablix`, na seção Detalhe e dentro do `Row Groups` da sua tabela. Pode criar quantos agrupamentos quiser.

Daí você pode definir as somas parciais e as totais por esses grupos.
Pode fazer fórmulas também nos seus campos, do tipo:

```
=sum(Fields!Campo1.Value)/CountDistinct(Fields!campo2Agrupado.Value)
```